# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(bx)}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}r^2\cdot\sin\big(\frac{b}{r^3}\big)\mathrm{d}r$

I had to solve a similar integral with cosine rather than sine and it was helpful to use a variable subsitution to obtain the format shown below. When it was cosine, this was evaluable using CPV. However, I don't think this is the case with sine and am searching for any insight into whether or not this integral is evaluable using CPV or otherwise.

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(bx)}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: It is divergent due to the behaviour in a right neighbourhood of the origin, $\frac{b}{r}$.

Comment: Even its principal value diverges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$I=\int\frac{\sin(bx)}{x^2}\,dx=b\, \text{Ci}(b x)-\frac{\sin (b x)}{x}$$
$$J=\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{\sin(bx)}{x^2}\,dx=\frac{\sin (b \epsilon )}{\epsilon }-b\,\text{Ci}(b \epsilon )$$ Developed as series
$$J=-b\, (\log (b)+\log (\epsilon )+\gamma -1)+\frac{b^3 \epsilon ^2}{12}+O\left(\epsilon
   ^4\right)$$ where you see the problem when $\epsilon \to 0$.